# Move list element position, based on values

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I am trying to create a web based view of our schools timetable for staff and students. I am using Django 1.8 to output this onto a table, if that makes any difference.

Sample Student CSV File: http://pastebin.com/Jf8My0RH
Sample Teacher CSV File: http://pastebin.com/ie3qeT3R

All data is stored in multiple CSV files. I have the student timetables working fine, using the code below:

```
def get_timetable(StudentCode):
    timetable = []

    with open(TT_BASE_DIR + 'NStudTT.txt') as student_timetable:
        reader = csv.DictReader(student_timetable, fieldnames=("StudentName","StudentCode","DayNo","PeriodNo","ClassCode","TeacherCode","RoomCode","RollClassCode","LessonType"))

    for row in reader:
        if row['StudentCode'] == StudentCode:
            for day in range(11):
                if int(row['DayNo']) == day:
                    timetable.append(row)

return(timetable[x:x+10] for x in range(0, len(timetable),10))
```

This returns a list of 10 lists, each with 10 dictionary items which I can output into a table.

I want to do the same for teachers, however they don't always have a full timetable. This is the code I am using to get the data out of the CSV file:

```
def get_teacher_timetable(TeacherCode):

    timetable = []

    with open(TT_BASE_DIR + 'NTRTimeT.txt') as teacher_timetable:
        reader = csv.DictReader(teacher_timetable, fieldnames=("TeacherCode", "RoomCode", "DayNo", "PeriodNo", "RollClassCode", "ClassCode"))

    for row in reader:
        if row['TeacherCode'] == TeacherCode:
            for day in range(11):
                if int(row['DayNo']) == day:
                    timetable.append(row)
    return(temp_timetable)
```

I can get it to return all the items, in a single list of dictionaries. What I need to be able to do is group the dictionaries by **DayNo**, then insert each group into a new list. However I want to insert the entries into the list according to **PeriodNo**. So if there was a spare in Period 4, it would create an element of NULL, or "", etc. At the end I should have a list of 10 lists, with 10 lessons / null in each one.

Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample data, it seems like the data will be in sorted order by TeacherCode, DayNo, PeriodNo so my solution is likewise.

To simplify, first filter the `reader` data structure so that it only contains relevant rows.

Use 2 for loops to loop over each day and time slot. If there is a corresponding row, add that row to the schedule. If there isn't, create a new dictionary with appropriate blank spaces and add it to the schedule.

Instead of compiling the list of lists when returning, I used a list to append all the time slots for one day, then appended that list to the full timetable after each day.

Here's the code:

```
def get_teacher_timetable(TeacherCode):

    timetable = []

    with open(TT_BASE_DIR + 'NTRTimeT.txt') as teacher_timetable:
        reader = csv.DictReader(teacher_timetable, fieldnames=("TeacherCode", "RoomCode", "DayNo", "PeriodNo", "RollClassCode", "ClassCode"))

    rows = iter([row for row in reader if row['TeacherCode'] == TeacherCode])
    row = next(rows,None)

    for day in range(1,11):
        day_schedule = []
        for period in range(1,11):
            if row and int(row['DayNo']) == day and int(row['PeriodNo']) == period:
                day_schedule.append(row)
                row = next(rows,None)
            else:
                new_row = {"TeacherCode":TeacherCode, "RoomCode":"", "DayNo":day, "PeriodNo":period, "RollClassCode":"", "ClassCode":""}
                day_schedule.append(new_row)
        timetable.append(day_schedule)

    return(timetable)
```

If there is a better way to iterate through the data, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks heaps. This is exactly what I needed.